# AngularJs URL with double slashes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a state in AngularJs:

```
...
.state('student',{
   url: '/students/:param1/:param2',
   template: 'templateLocation',
   controller: 'StudentsCtr'
})
....
```

If I provide `param1` and omit `param2` (optional parameter), the url looks like this (with 2 slashes at the end)

```
http://localhost/param1//
```

It works but I wish to know if it's OK to allow a link like this. Thanks!

Comment: Is second param optional?

Comment: Yes, it is optional

Comment: you can use it like `/:param1?param2` if `param2` is optional I think..

Comment: @tanmay How do I get the parameter(param2) from the controller?